# Django 3.2 ORM integrated in Tornado server

Tags: python, django, tornado

We're using django 2.2 before and can integrate django orm with our non-async tornado handlers but we're going to upgrade to django 3.2 where you can't run django orm(non-async) in a tornado handler(non-async) due to it being async-unsafe unless we use djangos' sync_to_async and make the handler async

Question:

- is there a way where we can still use django 3.2 orm in a tornado server non-async handler?
- or maybe what's the best way to integrate django orm in tornado handlers?

Comment: What is the difference between "sync" and "non-async"? Or when you say "django orm(sync)" do you mean "async"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice oh sorry, sync == non-async, also edited the question

Answer (score 0):

The docs mention a [`DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/async/#envvar-DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE) environment variable. If you set this variable (to any value), the warnings will be disabled:

```
import os

os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
```

Comment: Yea..but django issueed a warning not to use this in prod...any other way?

Comment: @user18960204 There won't be any problems if the code is not run concurrently. You mention in your question that the Tornado handlers are synchronous, so this seems okay as long as you don't run the ORM calls in a separate thread.

Comment: you mean, it's safe that we use the variable 'DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE'?, some of our handlers are async

Comment: @user18960204 If your handlers are async and you're using a blocking ORM, then what's the point? Doesn't that block the whole even loop? Which means none of the async handlers will run while there's an ORM operation going on. I don't know, I haven't tested it. But you should write some test cases to be sure.